# How to get compile/build date on Flutter App?

Tags: flutter

I know how to get the version using [package_info](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_info), but how to get the build timestamp on Runtime both on ios and android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a build shell script that creates/updates a Dart file in `lib/...` with constants holding the date before running `flutter build ...`.
You then import that file in your code and use it.

Comment: Could you please explain : how to  create.

Comment: It's just a text file that complies to Dart syntax. You create it like any other text file that you would create from whatever programming language you prefer for this task (bash, Dart, ...)

Answer (score 4):

I am adding my solution using [build package](https://pub.dev/packages/build) from Dart team.

1. Add dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dev_dependencies: 
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  build: ^2.4.0
```

2. Add this class in your project to any directory (I put mine in `/lib/common/build/` folder, you can put it in yours and don't forget to change directory in the code):

```dart
import 'dart:io';

// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:build/build.dart';

Builder appBuildTimestampGenerator(BuilderOptions options) => AppBuildTimestampGeneratorBuilder();

class AppBuildTimestampGeneratorBuilder implements Builder {
  @override
  final buildExtensions = {
    '.dart': ['.my_gen.dart']
  };

  @override
  Future<void> build(BuildStep _) async {
    final outputFile = File('lib/common/build/app_build_timestamp.g.dart');
    await outputFile.writeAsString('''
// Generated file on build.

/// Timestamp that records last build of the app. Can be shown in the app.
const int lastAppBuildTimestamp = ${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch};
''');
  }
}
```

3. Add `build.yaml` and put following inside (replace `package_name` and edit the directory):

```
builders:
  package_name|appBuildTimestampGenerator:
    import: 'package:package_name/common/build/app_build_timestamp_generator.dart'
    builder_factories: ['appBuildTimestampGenerator']
    build_extensions: {'.dart': ['.my_gen.dart']}
    auto_apply: root_package
    build_to: source
```

4. Run command:
   `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`
5. File named `app_build_timestamp.g.dart` is generated in your directory.
6. You can use `lastAppBuildTimestamp` in your project.

This works for me very well. Using Flutter 3.10.x and Dart 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest that you also consider basically rolling your own version of the package_info library which includes all the information you want to get from the platform code. I use the Gradle build files to update some variables on each build, which I then retrieve from Flutter.

Examining the package_info code shows that it is really a fairly simple MethodChannel use case. You could add anything that you can get from the native side.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Günter Zöchbauer answer...

1. Create a text file in your source folder and enter the following

> #!/bin/sh
>
> var = "final DateTime buildDate =
> DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(($(date "+%s000")));"
>
> echo "$var" > lib/build_date.dart

2. Save the text file as

> build_date_script.sh

3. In Android Studio, open Edit Configurations -> Add New Configuration and add a new 'Shell Script'
4. Give it a name, such as 'Write build date'
5. Select 'Script file' and enter the location of the 'build_date_script.sh' we created it stage 2.
6. Download and install GitBash https://gitforwindows.org/
7. Back to Android Studio, change the interpreter path to 'C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe'.
8. Uncheck 'Execute in terminal' and click 'Apply'
9. Then in your main flutter run configuration, add a 'Before launch' item, select 'Run another configuration' and choose the script config we named in stage 4.
10. Click OK.

Now every time you build it will create a new dart file in your lib folder called 'build_date.dart' with a variable called 'buildDate' for use as a build date within your application.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of getting the build time should rely on external tools in addition to modification in your code. Personally, I do it as follows (on Linux):

1. From your code, read an environment variable that should hold the build date (we will define it in the following steps).

   ```dart
   final buildDate = DateTime.parse(String.fromEnvironment('BUILD_DATE'));
   ```
2. Get the build date and store it in the environment variable.

   - You can either simply use the current date from the system:

   ```bash
   export BUILD_DATE=`date --iso-8601`
   ```

   - Or, if you use **Git**, you may like to use the date of the most recent commit:

   ```bash
   export BUILD_DATE=`git log -1 --format=%cd --date=short`
   ```
3. Compile the Flutter app with `--dart-define` to pass the value stored in the environment variable to the app code:

   ```bash
   flutter build web --dart-define=BUILD_DATE=$BUILD_DATE
   ```

   This command is for building a Web app but the steps are the same for any other type.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new file **compilation_variables_generator.dart** in your project **lib** folder and add:

> ```
> import 'dart:io';
>
> main () {
>   final file = File('lib/compile_time.dart');
>   file.writeAsStringSync(template(DateTime.now()));
> }
>
> String template(DateTime date) => '''
> class CompileTime {
> static const version = '0.4';
> static final date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(${date.millisecondsSinceEpoch});
> }
> ''';
> ```

2. Run it
3. Open the **Run/Debug Configurations** dialog, select your app configuration and in the **Before Launch** section add(+) **Run Another Configuration** and select **compilation_variables_generator.dart**
4. Use **CompileTime.date** in your code.