# Add date time of build/run to title text in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

My current code in `lib/main.dart` looks like this:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_bloc/flutter_form_bloc.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: LoginForm(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomFieldBlocValidators implements FieldBlocValidators {
  CustomFieldBlocValidators._();
  static String? number(dynamic value) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(value);
      print(value is num);
    }
    if (value == null || value == false || num.tryParse(value) == null) {
      return "Number input is required";
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class LoginFormBloc extends FormBloc<String, String> {
  final num1 = TextFieldBloc(
    validators: [
      FieldBlocValidators.required,
      CustomFieldBlocValidators.number
    ],
  );

  final num2 = TextFieldBloc(
    validators: [
      FieldBlocValidators.required,
      CustomFieldBlocValidators.number
    ],
  );

  LoginFormBloc() {
    addFieldBlocs(
      fieldBlocs: [
        num1,
        num2,
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void onSubmitting() async {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(DateTime.now());
      print(num1.value);
      print(num2.value);
    }

    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    if (Random().nextDouble() > 0.5) {
      emitSuccess();
    } else {
      emitFailure(failureResponse: 'This is an awesome error!');
    }
  }
}

class LoginForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LoginFormBloc(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final loginFormBloc = context.read<LoginFormBloc>();
          return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Basic Calculator - ')),
            body: FormBlocListener<LoginFormBloc, String, String>(
              onSubmitting: (context, state) {
                LoadingDialog.show(context);
              },
              onSuccess: (context, state) {
                LoadingDialog.hide(context);

                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SuccessScreen()));
              },
              onFailure: (context, state) {
                LoadingDialog.hide(context);

                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text(state.failureResponse!)));
              },
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                child: AutofillGroup(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                        textFieldBloc: loginFormBloc.num1,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Number 1',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.dialpad),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                        textFieldBloc: loginFormBloc.num2,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Number 2',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.dialpad),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: loginFormBloc.submit,
                            child: const Text('ADD'),
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: loginFormBloc.submit,
                            child: const Text('SUBTRACT'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoadingDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  static void show(BuildContext context, {Key? key}) => showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        useRootNavigator: false,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (_) => LoadingDialog(key: key),
      ).then((_) => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()));

  static void hide(BuildContext context) => Navigator.pop(context);

  const LoadingDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SuccessScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SuccessScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(Icons.tag_faces, size: 100),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            const Text(
              'Success',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 54, color: Colors.black),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LoginForm())),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.replay),
              label: const Text('AGAIN'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my class `LoginForm` where I set `appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Basic Calculator - ')),` I want to show the date and time of build/run in front of the hypen. I am not able to achieve it any way.

I have tried:

- const Text('Basic Calculator - '+DateTime.now())
- assigned the DateTime.now() to a variable and used the variable

but to no avail.

Comment: "show the date and time of build/run" ... build or run?  Pick one.  The answers would be very different.

Comment: @jamesdlin "build" would be good

Comment: If you want a build timestamp, you will need to have your build environment generate a `.dart` file or some asset on every build.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54089645/

Comment: @jamesdlin what about runtime then?

Comment: As mentioned by the other answers, at runtime you can just use `DateTime.now()` to get whatever the current time is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `const` and add `toString()`

```
Text('Basic Calculator - '+ DateTime.now().toString())
```

This works during run-time.

Comment: `Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.`

Comment: Did you remove the const before `Text` ?

Comment: This though is just for run time, not build.

Comment: @SahilHariyani yes I did

Comment: @li_boga see this answer if you want to get the build time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77658158/5008968